# Construct semi direct product $H \rtimes Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

EDIT: I'm only allowed to ask 6 questions and as my next question is similar to this, I thought I'd post it in this thread. The first question is the new one. The one under the underlined bit is the old question:

I tried it with looking at the previous posts. Now I'm trying to write it up and explain without looking at them.

I have

$$H = C_7 = \langle a \rangle \hspace{2cm} Q = C_3 = \langle b \rangle$$

To find my SDP's, I want to define a homomorphism, $\theta: Q \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(H)$. This is given by $\theta: C_3 \rightarrow C_6$. We know that non-trivial SDP's exist as $3$ divides $6$ and so we can see that we get $3$ SDP's altogether: $1$ trivial and $2$ non trivial.

Let $\mu$ generate $\mathrm{Aut}(C_7)$. I know want to define some $\mu$ of some order $r$ that sends $b \rightarrow b^{d^r} = b$. I.e I want to find some $d^r \equiv 1 \mod 7$. To find my $d$, I first split $6 = 2 \times 3$. Here we see that gcd$(2,7) = 1$ and so this $r$ exists for some $d$. We then get

$$2^1 \equiv -5 \mod 7$$
$$2^2 \equiv -3 \mod 7$$
$$2^3 \equiv 1 \mod 7$$

Therefore, I get that $\mu: b \mapsto b^3$.

Now, I have this, I can now define two multiplication orders (for my two non trivial SDP's) and construct the SDP's. As $\mathrm{Aut}(C_7)$ is cyclic, we get that $C_6 = \langle \mu \rangle$.From here, out two elements of order $r = 3$ are $\mu^2$ and $\mu^4$. Using the multiplication order

$$ ba = a\theta(a^{-1})(b)$$

where $\theta(a^{-1})(b) = \mu^{2,4}$, we get our first SDP to be when we map $\mu^2$.

$$\mu: b \mapsto b^3 \implies \mu^2: b \mapsto b^9$$

$9 \equiv 2 \mod 7$ and so we get $\mu^2: b \mapsto b^2$ and so our first multiplictive order is defined as $ba = ab^2$.

For the second one, we know have $\mu^4 : b \mapsto b^{3^4}$. $3^4 = 81 \equiv 4 \mod 7$ and so we get that $\mu^4 : b \mapsto b^4$. So our second multiplicative order is defined as $ba = ab^4$.

From here, we conclude that we have 3 SDP's. One is the direct product so

$$G \cong H \times Q \cong C_6 \times C_3$$

We then have two more groups whose elements follow the multiplicative orders $ba = ab^2$ and $ba = ab^4$.

Is this correct?

---

Hopefully this will be the last SDP question I post because I get how to construct them. I don't have an answer to this as well because I've adjusted the question I was asked (how many SDPs are there) to find the SDP. This is what I did:

$$H = C_{42} \hspace{2cm} Q = C_3$$

Let $H = \langle a \rangle, Q = \langle b \rangle, \mathrm{Aut}(H) = \langle \mu \rangle$.

An SDP is a homomorphism, $\theta : Q \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(H)$. So my first step is to calculate $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$. $42 = 2 \times 3 \times 7$. So this gives us $\mathrm{Aut}(H) \cong C_2 \times C_6 \cong C_{12}$. As $3$ divides $12$, we know there is a nontrivial SDP.

We know that $\mu$ generates $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ and so we want to find an element in $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ which has order $12$. We can work this out and say $\mu^3$ is one of these elements.

We want to define some $\mu : b \mapsto b^k$. We can say that therefore $k = 2$ as two $2$ is the lowest integer whose multiplicative integer is $\equiv 2 \mod 12$. So now we have definied $\mu: b \mapsto b^2$.

We want to work out the multiplicative order

$$ba = a\theta(a^{-1})(b)$$

Where $\theta(a^{-1})(b)$ generates $\mu$. Seeing as we definied $\mu : b \mapsto b^2$, we therefore get $\mu^3: b \mapsto b^{2^3} = b^8$ and so we get our SDP as a group with multiplicative order

$$ba = ab^8.$$

Right now thats what i've got. I'm still working through the next bit to write it the $(a^i, b^j)$ form but my lecturer hasn't been writing it like that so I think the multiplicative order answer would be ok in the exam.

Comment: Don't rush it: $\,C_2\times C_6\ncong C_{12}\, $!

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh ok, so then I want elements of order $3$ in $C_2 \times C_6$. There are none in $C_2$ but in $C_6$ I have some and so I can define $\mu$ as $\mu^2$. Then blah blah blah and I get my multiplicative order as $ba = ba^4$?

Comment: That should be $ba = ab^4$

Comment: Indeed, @Kaish...or, as adviced before, use ordered pairs. :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Lol thanks. Yeah, I will defo look at them. I might not ask as many question on them because I think people are getting annoyed with my constant SDP questions, but if I can put them in that form, atleast then I will be able to see the group easier for myself

Comment: Your post has so many mistakes that it is difficult to help you much!  ${\rm Aut}(H)$ is not cyclic, so you do not have ${\rm Aut}(H) = \langle \mu \rangle$. As already pointed out $C_2 \times C_6 \not\cong C_{12}$. You do not want to find an element of ${\rm Aut}(H)$ of order 12, you want to find one of order 3. What do you mean by $\mu^3$ is one of those elements? Whatever $\mu$ is, $\mu^3$ will not have order 3. You write $\mu:b \to b^2$, but that is an element of ${\rm Aut}(Q)$ not ${\rm Aut}(H)$. And $a \to a^2$ does not define an automorphism of $H$ since $|a|=42$ but $|a^2|=21$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok, I get how to correct all those mistakes except for that bit where $a \rightarrow a^2$. How do I know what $a$ goes to to define an automorphism of $H$?

Comment: Would it be $a \rightarrow a^3$ because that has multiplicative order congruent to $-3 \mod 12$? Or am I not looking at $\mod 12$?

Comment: You could just use Cauchy's theorem to show that $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$ has an element of order $3$ without bothering with $C_2\times C_6$.

Comment: So is my answer of $ba = ab^4$ wrong?

Comment: By the way, using $ba=ab^4$ yields a group of order $63$, $C_3\times C_7\rtimes C_3 = C_3\times F_{21}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question**:

To find elements of $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$ look for $x\mapsto x^d$ for $d$ relatively prime to $42$.  If you compose this map with itself, you get $x\mapsto (x^d)^d=x^{d^2}$, if you do it again you get $x\mapsto x^{d^3}$ and so on.  If you're looking for an automorphism of order $r$, what you want is $x\mapsto x^{d^r}=x$, which means that $d^r\equiv 1 \pmod{42}$.

Let's hold up one sec: why does $d^r\equiv 1 \pmod{42}$?

> Every element has order dividing $42$ in $C_{42}$.  In particular, $1$ has order $42$, so if $x^{d^r}$ is supposed to be equal to $x$ for every $x\in C_{42}$, including $1$, we need for $d^r$ to be some multiple of $42$ plus one.

So, you want to find an element of order $3$ in $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$.  You know that one exists by Cauchy's theorem, since $|\text{Aut}(C_{42})|=12$.  Let's start by looking at maps $x\mapsto x^d$ for different $d$ and see what orders we can get.

$42=2\times 3 \times 7$ so the smallest number for which $\text{gcd}(d,42)=1$ is $d=5$.  Let's find the order of $x\mapsto x^5$ in $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
5&\equiv&5\pmod{42}\\
5^2&\equiv&25\pmod{42}\\
5^3&\equiv&41\pmod{42}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Whoa whoa whoa - so $5^3\equiv-1\pmod{42}$?  Recall my comment on [DonAntonio's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/275542/12952) in your other thread on multiplicative order - this means that $5$ has multiplicative order $6$ modulo $42$.

Thus $x\mapsto x^5$ has order $6$ in $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$.  But so what?  We were looking for an automorphism of order $3$.  Well, all you have to do to turn an element of order $6$ into an element of order $3$ is square it.  So $x\mapsto x^{25}$ has order $3$ in $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$.

Now that you explicitly have the element of order $3$ in $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$ I think you can finish the problem.

---

**Second question**:

You are mostly correct, but there are a couple things:

When you're doing the $d^r\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ thing, you are finding the multiplicative order of $d$ mod $n$.  Equivalently, $x\mapsto x^d$ is an automorphism of order $r$ in $\text{Aut}(C_n)$ (assuming $\text{gcd}(d,n)=1$). So, $\mu$ is a generator of $\text{Aut}(C_p)$ if and only if $\mu:x\mapsto x^d$ where $d$ has order $p-1$ mod $p$.

Here what you want to do is find some automorphism of order $3$ to map $a$ to.  You correctly found that the multiplicative order of $2$ is $3$ mod $7$, so you have that $x\mapsto x^2$ is an automorphism of order $3$ in $\text{Aut}(C_7)$.

From there you determine that the generator of $\text{Aut}(C_7)$ is $\mu:x\mapsto x^3$, **which is true** but I'm not sure how you got it from the preceding computation.  If you noticed that $3^2\equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ then your reasoning was correct, but if you concluded that $d^r\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ implies that $x\mapsto x^r$ generates $\text{Aut}(C_7)$, that is not true.

With that said, the rest of your computations are correct; indeed $\langle a,b|a^3,b^7,b^a=b^2\rangle$ and $\langle a,b|a^3,b^7,b^a=b^4\rangle$ are the correct semidirect products.  As it turns out, however, these are isomorphic, so actually you have only two distinct SDPs (including the trivial semidirect product $C_7\times C_2$).

Comment: From there, I can still use my $\mu^2$ and then I can get my multiplication order to be $ba = ab^{25^2}$?

Comment: You're good with just $ba=ab^{25}$.  In this case the $\mu$ is just $x\mapsto x^5$ so $\mu^2$ is $x\mapsto x^{25}$. (That is what I was saying in the $2^\text{nd}$ to last paragraph.)

Comment: Can I do another question and post it up?

Comment: Sure man, keep em comin

Comment: @Kaish Updated.

Comment: I said it was because I did $\mu: x \mapsto x^r$. What do you mean by the $3^2 \equiv 2 \mod 7$ bit, how does this show it? I'm going to try another question tomorrow, although I'm running out of examples in my lecture notes and homework sheets. Have you got any good ones?

Comment: I remmeber the answer @Aurtor gave here when I see your complete answer, Alexander. +1

Comment: @BabakSorouh Thanks; that is the highest of compliments. :)

Comment: @Kaish Since $\mu:x\mapsto x^3$ is a generator of $\text{Aut}(C_{42})$ and has order $6$, $\mu^2$ has order $3$, and in particular $\mu^2:x\mapsto x^9$.  But since $3^2=9\equiv 2\pmod{7}$, $\mu^2:x\mapsto x^2$.  About more problems: it might be interesting for you to try making some semidirect products where the groups are not cyclic, just to get familiar with different automorphism groups. You could see if you can follow this answer for example http://math.stackexchange.com/a/264272/12952 Otherwise, I would say just pick random $n$ and $m$, and construct all possible $C_n\rtimes C_m$.